# C++ Fastest way to parse through a file

Tags: c++, string, boost, char

I have a file which I have opened using:

ifstream ifile(FilePath)

The file contains, say 10 lines of data and each line contains an evenly-incrementing number of comma separated values (like a pyramid). So first line has 1 value, second line has 2 values and so on....

I wanted to do the following, all within one function (whilst traversing the file char array just the once):

-Every time I encounter a newline character, I can increment a parameter passed in by value (which, when the function exits, I have the number of lines in the file).

-I also wanted to store each line of the file in an array. What would be the best way to "glue" together all the characters between newline characters?

I'd prefer to use statically-allocated arrays, but the problem is I only know the size of the array once I have performed step 1 (counting how many new line characters there are). Would it be quicker to perform a double-parse for this (one parse to count how many lines, then use that value to allocate a static array) or single parse, but insert into a dynamic array?

The emphasis on this is to write fast code (so not being OO-friendly is not a concern)

Apologies if I am asking a lot, hopefully you can see I have given this some thought.

EDIT, example file:

> a
>
> b,c
>
> d,e,f,g,h
>
> j,k,l,m,n,o,p

From this file I would want to achieve:

- Knowledge that there are 4 lines in the file
- A non-dynamic array containing each line
- The number of elements in the second line

Comment: Have you looked at [Boost.Spirit](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/).Qi? There's a learning curve, and compile times aren't plesant if you aren't using precompiled headers, but the runtime performance can be great if you minimize backtracking.

Comment: The code is on my other computer, but I originally used while(getline(File, line)){vector.push_back(line);} but that was just putting line-by-line into a vector. Im now thinking if I pass char by char I can reduce the number of parses/splitting of lines

Comment: @ildjarn Could you elaborate on precompiled headers? I thought for the boost libraries some were precompiled and some weren't- and you dont get to choose?

Comment: can you provide an example input (file contents) and outputs of the process you are trying to achieve

Comment: @user997112 : Boost.Spirit is header-only, so no _linking_ is required; [precompiled headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header) are orthogonal to linking.

Comment: I would use Boost.Spirit, but this require some (well worth it) learning)

Comment: @111111 Would Spirit just be for the parsing? What would you recommend as the quickest way for for opening the file into memory?

Comment: You would still feed it a `std::ifstream` or whatever you choose, it would do the parsing

Comment: Not sure why anybody would use boost::spirit for such a simple problem. Its like 5 lines of C++ code.

Comment: @LokiAstari : Spirit addresses the question's title moreso than the question's content. user997112, I doubt it will matter much, but you can use a memory-mapped file instead of a standard stream to load the data into memory.

Comment: @ildjarn: I think you misunderstand the meaning of the word `parse` in this context it just means read. There is not enough complexity in this input to justify writing a grammar. In short it is a really bad suggestion.

Comment: @LokiAstari : Hence a comment rather than an answer. Something get you upset today, dear?

Comment: If this task is already difficult, Spirit is not going to make it easier. Just use your while loop and add the lines to a vector, only split the 2nd string.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of examples in existing posts on how to do this.

if you want to use ifstream to read in the file once, you can do something like this:

```
std::ifstream in("myfile");

std::stringstream buffer;
buffer << in.rdbuf();

std::string contents(buffer.str());
```

Comment: so ifstream wasn't the best way to read the file into memory?

Comment: added how to get file in a buffer using ifstream read (block of data) and store as string

Comment: This really only gets you anything if the file is huge because disc access is already buffered. And if it is huge then you have other problems. But sscanf() may be fast but its not safe. Better to use the slower but safer operator >> it may be slower but it is fast enough for this problem.

Comment: He asked for the fastest code, nothing about safety.  My my we are critical, down vote?  really?

Comment: Hey guys, Ive just compared boost::interprocess file mapping with ifstream and the boost implementation is double as quick